# SonarQube missing Package Tangle Index and Dependencies drilldown information

Tags: sonarqube, static-analysis

We have SonarQube up and running, and it's producing a nice dashboard with a lot of general info.

Sections like Duplications and Unit Tests Coverage have both dashboard info, and detail info you can drill down to.

Drilling down from Package Tangle Index, Cycles, Between Packages, and Between Files just gives the number listed in the dashboard. So, something has done the analysis, but the details have not made their way into the database. I can see from this 2010 article that Sonar does have a facility for displaying details:

http://www.sonarqube.org/fight-back-design-erosion-by-breaking-cycles-with-sonar/

Does anyone know how to get the Package Tangle Info details to display?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Design information have been removed in version 5.2. See http://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-5-2-in-screenshots/ for more details.

Comment: Will this be available again ?